# How to show title and URL from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

I hope someone can help me with this puzzle!

I have this code:

```
<?php
    
    $user = 'myuser';
    $pass = 'mypass';
    
    try{
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mybase', $user, $pass);
        foreach($dbh->query('SELECT title FROM ads_listing') as $title);
        foreach($dbh->query('SELECT slug FROM ads_listing') as $slug){
        print_r($slug);
        print_r($title);
        }
    
        $dbh = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        print "ERROR!:" . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
    ?>
```

It display:

```
Array ( [slug] => laptop-dell-e6420-in-good-condition-tj304mkn910a8 [0] => laptop-dell-e6420-in-good-condition-tj304mkn910a8 ) 1Array ( [title] => VW POLO Comfortline [0] => VW POLO Comfortline ) 1Array ( [slug] => vw-polo-comfortline-rf839h9c9d065 [0] => vw-polo-comfortline-rf839h9c9d065 ) 1Array ( [title] => VW POLO Comfortline [0] => VW POLO Comfortline )
```

The goal is to display from my table 10 random titles as an URL with the slug like: [VW POLO Comfortline](https://www.example.com/vw-polo-comfortline-rf839h9c9d065), [Laptop dell e6420 in good condition](https://www.example.com/laptop-dell-e6420-in-good-condition-tj304mkn910a8),.

How can I do it please?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `LIMIT` and `RAND()` in your query like:

```
SELECT title, slug FROM ads_listing ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

then use this query and function `fetch_assoc()` to have the result in associative array type:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT title, slug FROM ads_listing ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";
$result = $connection -> query($query);
while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
    // you can use $row which has been read from table randomly
    ...
}
?>
```

in the previous code, `$connection` is the connection which has been got from `PDO` class. Obviously, you do not have to use exactly like what I wrote, but I suggest to you use one.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things going on here from a puristic point of view, but I think there are two things that are preventing you from solving this:

- You don't fetch your data in a single query
- You don't loop your data in a single loop

Going along with the assumption that `$dbh->query()` returns an associative array, you could do the following:

```php
$user = 'myuser';
$pass = 'mypass';

try{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mybase', $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    print "ERROR!:" . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$ads = $dbh->query('SELECT title, slug FROM ads_listing');
foreach ($ads as $ad) {
    $title = $ad['title'];
    $slug = $ad['slug'];
}
```